# Navigate from one external template to another with ionic framework doesn't work properly

Tags: ionic-framework

So in my index.html file, I have the following code, essentially linking two external html pages.

```
<!--First Template-->
<script id="views/profileView.html" type="text/ng-template">
 <div ng-include="'./views/profileView.html'"></div>
</script>

<!--Second Template-->
<script id="views/callView.html" type="text/ng-template">
 <div ng-include="'./views/callView.html'"></div>
</script>
```

The first template to load is profileView, which loads fine. In that template I have a button, on click will load the state of the second template. The second page doesn't load completely. Its a partial transition. I noticed this problem is because I was trying to load a state of another external template.
If I was to not exclude the content into an external template and just write it out in the index file itself, I don't get this problem.  Have anyone experienced such issues when navigating from one external page to another? Are there any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

if i were you i would use the angular $stateProvider, so you would have something like this

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ionic']);

    app.config('$stateProvider', function($stateProvder){
     $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/home',
          templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
        }).state('pageone', {
          url: '/pageone',
          templateUrl: 'templates/pageone.html'
        });
});
```

Then in your index.html you just have an ion nav view like so:

```
 <ion-nav-view animation="no-animation"></ion-nav-view>
```

then to navigate states in your controller you just include $state like you would $scope call this for example: `$state.go('home')`

you can read more about it and see more examples here: http://learn.ionicframework.com/formulas/navigation-and-routing-part-1/

Comment: Hi. I'm actually doing exactly that.. trust me, if the templates are in different files, then when you try to $state.go to another state, you will notice an incomplete transition. In fact the view for the second template will not fully load.

Comment: does this happen on an emulator on on the device? and if on a device is it android, ios, windows phone?

Comment: also why do you use script tags to tie your files to the index page. I am using the state provider and simple point the state templateUrl to the relative file path and it works great. Have you tried that without using the ng-includes and the script tags?

Comment: This happens on all devices. No the problem is not observed if you don't break your index file into templates(i.e. not using the ng-includes). Problem is my index page could grow significantly which I don't like and I was hoping that ng-includes would allow me  break it up for easy development and maintenance. You should try it out, its really peculiar  behaviour.

Comment: so here is what i do, i have all my views in a folder in seperate html files. My index.html is a total of about 50 lines of html. if you put all of your views into separate files in in a templates or views folder and simply tie them to a state using the state provider then it solves your problem. It allows for easy maintenance and development. So i have www/templates/"lots of separate html files go here". Then i simply point to them with the state templateUrl. none of them go in my index.html files and i do not use any ng-include. you can break your file into templates without using ng-include

Comment: I see.. I was under the impression that we had to tie the templates to our index file and then have the provider stateprovider point to them. Thanks a lot. Ill try this out. The whole point of the ng-includes was kind of confusing.

Comment: its all good! i hope it works for you. Yeah i thought that at first too but you can simple point the the file from the state provider. some of my templates are just divs with stuff inside them. also make sure to bind the controller onto the template or, tie them into the .state with controller: 'yourcontrollername', i think

Comment: Awesome Glad to hear :D